# Caused by android.view.InflateException on Android 10 API level 29

Tags: android, android-layout, android-support-library, android-xml, androidx

My app runs on every API level, but failing to load on some specific devices sometime.
this time it's failing to find resources which are already there on a HUAWEI device, with device details as follow:

```
Build.DEVICE : HWJNY 
Build.FINGERPRINT : HUAWEI/JNY-LX1/HWJNY:10/HUAWEIJNY-L21/10.1.0.388C432:user/release-keys 
Build.HARDWARE : kirin810 
Build.PRODUCT : JNY-LX1 
Location : RO 
Brand:HUAWEI
Model:JNY-LX1
Orientation: Portrait
RAM free: 1.57 GB
Disk free: 103.26 GB
Operating system
Version:Android 10
Orientation: Portrait
Rooted:No
```

**Stacktrace:**

```
Non-fatal Exception: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.package/com.package.onboarding.VerifyPhoneNumberActivity}: android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #49 in com.package:layout/activity_verify_phone_number_new: Binary XML file line #49 in com.package:layout/activity_verify_phone_number_new: Error inflating class androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3897)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

more to stacktrace:

```
Caused by android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: Resource ID #0x7f080271
       at android.content.res.ResourcesImpl.getValue(ResourcesImpl.java:328)
       at android.content.res.Resources.getValue(Resources.java:1468)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.createDrawableIfNeeded(ResourceManagerInternal.java:179)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:144)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.ResourceManagerInternal.getDrawable(ResourceManagerInternal.java:135)
       at androidx.appcompat.content.res.AppCompatResources.getDrawable(AppCompatResources.java:104)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageHelper.loadFromAttributes(AppCompatImageHelper.java:63)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:82)
       at androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView.<init>(AppCompatImageView.java:69)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance0(Constructor.java)
       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:343)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createView(LayoutInflater.java:864)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:1016)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.createViewFromTag(LayoutInflater.java:971)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflate(LayoutInflater.java:1133)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.rInflateChildren(LayoutInflater.java:1094)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:692)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:536)
       at android.view.LayoutInflater.inflate(LayoutInflater.java:483)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatDelegateImpl.setContentView(AppCompatDelegateImpl.java:699)
       at androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity.setContentView(AppCompatActivity.java:195)
       at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:303)
       at androidx.databinding.DataBindingUtil.setContentView(DataBindingUtil.java:284)
       at com.talkhome.onboarding.VerifyPhoneNumberActivity.onCreate(VerifyPhoneNumberActivity.kt:53)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8085)
       at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:8073)
       at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1320)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3870)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:4076)
       at android.app.servertransaction.LaunchActivityItem.execute(LaunchActivityItem.java:91)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.executeCallbacks(TransactionExecutor.java:149)
       at android.app.servertransaction.TransactionExecutor.execute(TransactionExecutor.java:103)
       at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:2473)
       at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
       at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:219)
       at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:8349)
       at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java)
       at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:513)
       at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1055)
```

**ImageView where inflation is failing:**

```
<androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView
            android:id="@+id/img"
            app:layout_constraintHeight_percent="0.35"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="0dp"
            app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintRight_toRightOf="parent"
            app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/guide_line"
            app:srcCompat="@drawable/mobileverification" />
```

[image: Where the src png images are here with all resolutions]

**Any idea what could be failing it?**

Comment: added all stacktrace.  on all devices its working fine. but not on this specific device.

Comment: Since the resource is a png and not a vector drawable try with app:src

Comment: oh, I see, @TaranmeetSingh you may be right. thanks for the heads up.

I'll change it to that.

Comment: @Wajid did this resolve your problem? Post an answer if yes.